# My session unset every time when page refresh

Tags: php, session

I am try to making website there i have log in system for admin when admin successfully log in than assign session but this session expire when page refresh.Check below i am showing you what i have done.

**Html**

```
      <form  action="../../system/access/checking.php" class="form-signin">

    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"  required autofocus>
    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  required>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  onclick="submitfom();" >Sign in</a>


  </form>
```

**Ajax**

```
function submitfom() {
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "../../system/access/checking.php",
         data: {user: $("#user").val(),pass: $("#pass").val()},
         success: function(data){
      if(data == true ){     
      window.location.href = '../../index.php';
        } else {
          $('#show-error').slideDown( "slow",function (){$('#show- error').html(data);$('#show-error').css("display","inline");});
        };
     }
      });
  }
```

**php**

```
 include('../../../config.php');
 if((isset($_POST['user'])) && (isset($_POST['pass'])) ){
 $user = $_POST['user'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM admin_user WHERE user ='".$user."' ");
       $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT pass FROM admin_user WHERE pass ='".$pass."' ");

       $result= mysql_num_rows($query);
       $result2= mysql_num_rows($query2);

        if((!empty($result)) && (!empty($result2))){
          session_set_cookie_params('3600');
           session_start();  
            $_SESSION['admin']=$user ;
            session_write_close();
            echo true;

         }
      else {
           echo "Please Write correct <strong>username and password</strong>";
          }
                }
      else {
                 echo "Some thing miss";
           }
```

Comment: `session_start()` needs to to go at the *top* of every page you wish to use sessions on.

Comment: please elaborate on debug progress you have made. Also it is unclear what is being asked here.

Comment: you need `session_start();` on every page, also you need to update your mysql to mysqli or pdo or your going to get hacked.

Comment: `session_start();` i am using already on every page on top.

Comment: You should also refrain from using `mysql_` functions. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5, and will be removed in the next release of PHP. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used for querying databases.

Comment: Also, you are putting user input directly in to your SQL query, which allows for an injection attack. Look at using parameters and/or sanitize the data first.

Comment: @AffanAhmad, you are **NOT** using `session_start()` on every page on top. First line should read `session_start();`.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid this one is not complete code.

Answer (score 1):

delete

```
session_write_close();
```

move

```
session_start()
```

to the top of your scripts (or better set session.autostart parameter to true in PHP config.

```
mysql_query()
```

will be removed in the next PHP release, use PDO instead.

You have 2 SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your code.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM admin_user WHERE user ='".$user."' ");
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT pass FROM admin_user WHERE pass ='".$pass."' ");
```

if you post `' or id=1` in both fields, you're get logged in admin (you can brutforce fields like id, email, username and other to get correct. And this list will be small).